# Laravel displays PHP code instead of executing it

Tags: laravel

Yesterday I deployed my Laravel app on a server and everything worked fine. I woke up this morning and the app is not working properly anymore and all I can see is the following text when I try to access the website:

```php
    <?php

    /**
     * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
     *
     * @package  Laravel
     * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
     */

    define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register The Auto Loader
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
    | our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
    | into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
    | loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
    |
    */

    require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Turn On The Lights
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
    | This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
    | will load up this application so that we can run it and send
    | the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
    |
    */

    $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Run The Application
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
    | through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
    | the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
    | and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
    |
    */

    $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

    $response = $kernel->handle(
        $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
    );

    $response->send();

    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

I made no changes to the app or server. Does someone know what is going on and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you dd($response->send()); and add the result screen capture to your post ?

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI In what file exactly if I may ask?

Comment: you may not have made changes to the server but something must have changed. Try checking your webserver config to make sure its how you left it

Comment: At the end of index.php file you will see " $response->send()", dump it so we can see returned response type and content to the browser

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI I added `dd($response->send());` to the `index.php` file and nothing happens, it just displays the PHP code again, including `dd($response->send());`. It's not executed for some reason.

Comment: It t might be PHP is not enabled in your web server configuration
Check this link http://www.expertphp.in/article/php-code-display-in-browser-instead-of-executing-it . Hope it helps

Comment: Did you configure your webserver correctly? This might have to do something with a missing/fauly htaccess file

Comment: What you are seeing is the source code of Laravel index.php file. You webserver is serving the file "as-is", most likely because your PHP server is not running (or crashed overnight). Connect to your machine and restart the web server.

Comment: @MA 
what is your system operation? linux or windows?

Comment: I've the same issue, All other laravel and PHP are running fine only 1 is not working. Does anyone has the same issue? I'm using MacOS with Valet also tried in Windows with Laragon.

Answer (score 0):

install the following package `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php` and hopefully it will resolve your issue